# Determining if a set is measurable by upper and lower sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

I have the following question regarding Lebesgue measure:
If $A,B$ are measurable sets and I have $m(A\setminus E)=0$ and $m(E\setminus B)=0$, is it enough to determine that $E$ is measurable? We do not know whether $E\subset A$ or $B\subset E$ or any information of that sort, but we do know that $A\cap E\not = \emptyset$ $B\cap E\not = \emptyset$. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Consider the counter example where A and B are two measurable sets and E is a non-measurable set disjoint from both A and B.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the note

Comment: You should really write $A\setminus E$ instead of $A-E$, because the second notation often means something different ($A-E=\{a-e:a\in A, e\in E\}$).

Comment: @user247327 ??? If $B$ and $E$ are disjoint then $E\setminus B=E$, so one of the hypotheses says exactly that $m(E)=0$, hence $E$ is measurable. (Or to put it another way: It's implicit in the hypothesis $m(E\setminus B)=0$ that $E\setminus B$ is measurable. If the two sets are disjoint this says exactly that $E$ is measurable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $A=\{2\}$, $B=[0,1]$, and let $E$ be the union of $\{2\}$ with a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$. Then

- $A\setminus E$ is empty
- $E\setminus B = \{2\}$
- $A\cap E$ and $B\cap E$ are nonempty